# How do I create a procedural mask for mountains texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

*I'm going to try to explain this as well as possible but feel free to ask any questions for clarification.* I have mountains and plains (picture below) and I'm trying to create a procedural mask that will differentiate between the mountains and the plains by creating a mask vertically along the "Z" axis to pick at what height you want the mask.

You can see an example of what I'm talking about [here.](https://youtu.be/yrMee2gcS20?t=481)

The node setup in that video doesn't work in my instance. **How do you achieve this effect?**
[image]

Comment: they're using node wrangler and you don't appear to have it enabled, it's in edit > preferences > add-ons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use object Z coordinates? You can use a ColorRamp or Greater Than node to control where the cutoff point is:

[image]

You mention in your question that the node setup in the video you linked doesn’t work for you, but you don’t mention why, so if this approach doesn’t work for you, either, please add more details to your question.

Comment: Bam! Yes! Thank you so much!